# How long does it take to add a new view to couchdb to a large data set

Tags: php, wordpress, couchdb

We have a couchdb database filled with 6.4 GB of data and about 60788 documents. I just added a new design view and when I reloaded a page that sorts by the new view, and it is taking a very long time.

About how long should I be expected to wait for such a large dataset. all the view is doing is emitting a string property.

Comment: It should be pretty linear: If you divide the time it needed by the count, this is the time a insertion into the view of one document will take about. In my experience CouchDB is not fast for insertions but better for queries.

Comment: it looks like it just finished. up. took about 30 minutes. I just realized there was a status button that gave the percentage. That really helped me not worry as much